# Building a 3 dimension DataFrame and its heat_map() in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to build 3-dimensional DataFrame as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ii = [days for days in np.arange(10, 30, 10)]
jj = [days for days in np.arange(20, 50, 10)]
kk = [days for days in np.arange(50, 200, 50)]
all_sharpes = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ii:
    for j in jj:
        for k in kk:
            all_sharpes[i][j][k] = i+j+k

all_sharpes
```

But I got errors as follow:

```
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 10
```

Besides, I want to get its heap-map().

Comment: What exactly is a `heap-map()`?

Comment: Sorry for the mistyping. It should be heat_map().

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame is inherently 2D.  If you want a 3D thing in Pandas, it's called Panel: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html

Also, note that you are getting exactly none of the benefit of Pandas with code like this:

```
ii = [days for days in np.arange(10, 30, 10)]
```

If you just leave it as `np.arange(10, 30, 10)` it is OK.  There is zero need to use a list comprehension to cumbersomely turn it into a list.

Comment: Recommending a [deprecated class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-panel) to a beginner may not be the best idea.

Comment: @DSM: I sort of agree with you, but there is no proper alternative in Pandas.  The Pandas developers seem to be suggesting that users abandon Pandas in favor of xarray, but I wasn't about to suggest *that* to a newcomer.

Comment: Depends on the use case, I think.  If you're working with large datacubes you might as well switch to xarray now, because pandas is going to fight you every step of the way.  If you're working with smaller objects, following the recommendation in the docs of using a multiindex works well enough.